# Clearing entiyManager during batch inserts

Tags: spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

There is a concern: could injected EntityManager to Spring service affect other transactions, being processed in parallel?
My use case is: service has to load plenty of entities from DB (tens of thousands approx.), set some extralogic,map into another entity, persist, than send to middleware. The trigger is @Scheduled component, which works asynchronously with other schedulers. For performance purpose, batch inserts are being used, 30 entity for each batch with Spring JPA work the best. Going further, it is recomended to clear the first-level cache after each insert. Being localy implemented, it decreases significantly the number of transactions and flushes. The only thing I am afraid of is the possibility to evict data from other Hibernate-managed caches.
The code:

```
@Override
    public void cronJobFoo(Type type) {
        final int count = repository.countByTypes(type);
        int page = 0;
        do {
            Page<Message> cur = repository.findAllByTypesOrderByCreatedDateTime(type, PageRequest.of(page, pageSize));
            final List<MessageHistory> history = cur.getContent().stream()
                    .map([*transform data*])
                    .toList();
            historyRepo.saveAllAndFlush(history);
            entityManager.clear();
            history.stream()
                    .forEach([*middleware sending request*]);
            page++;
        } while (page * pageSize < count);
    }
```

EntityManager was injected with no @PersistentContext annotation, if it matters.
Any thoughts?